# Migrating from MySQL Server to MariaDB

Tags: linux, mysql, convert, mariadb

I've heard that MariaDB has better performance than MySQL-Server. I'm running software that makes an intensive use of MySQL, thats why I want to try upgrading to MariaDB.

Please tell me your experiences doing this conversion, and instructions or tips.

Also, which files I should take care of for making a backup of MySQL-Server, so if something goes wrong with MariaDB, I could rollback to MySQL without issues?
I would use this but I'm not sure if it's enough to get a full backup of MySQL-Server confs and databases:

- mysqldump --all-databases
- backup /etc/mysql

My Environment:

```
uname -a (Debian Lenny)

Linux charizard 2.6.26-2-amd64 #1 SMP Thu Sep 16 15:56:38 UTC 2010 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

MySQL Server Version:

```
Server version          5.0.51a-24+lenny4
```

MySQL Client: 5.0.51a

Statistics:

```
Threads: 25  Questions: 14690861  Slow queries: 9  Opens: 21428  Flush tables: 1  Open tables: 128  Queries per second avg: 162.666
Uptime:                 1 day 1 hour 5 min 13 sec
```

Comment: Your English is great! :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the MariaDB website, you do not need to dump anything. Just install the new binaries and reuse existing data directory. See:

http://kb.askmonty.org/v/how-can-i-upgrade-from-mysql-to-mariadb

I would still advise to do a backup though. To be paranoid:

1. tar cvfz /etc.tar.gz /etc
2. tar cvfz /var/lib/mysql.backup.tar.gz /var/lib/mysql # while mysql is stopped, as Kevin mentioned
3. mysqldump --all-databases

Answer (score 1):

You could make a backup of `/var/lib/mysql` after shutting MySQL down; the data files are stored there.

Answer (score 1):

mariadb is definitely better performing mysql version for both myisam and innodb performance. Especially mariadb 5.2.x see http://vbtechsupport.com/606/

to upgrade on centos at least, i basically

1. backup mysql databases via mysqldump
2. yum remove mysql
3. rpm -i mariadb 5.2.x rpms
4. run mysql_upgrade to check compatibility
5. if issues, restore mysqldump sql dump then rerun mysqlcheck --check-upgrade
6. then recompile php making sure --with-mysql=/path/to/mysql and --with-mysqli=/path/to/mysql_config are included to use mariadb 5.2.x client libraries.

Comment: Giving RPM commands to Debian user is a bit useless. And it is better to use standard distribution packages whenever possible rather then manually compiling packages which won't automatically or easily upgrade when there are security/bug fixes later.